# Floating figures and tikzposter

Tags: floats, positioning, posters, tikzposter

I'm trying to use the class `tikzposter` to write a scientific poster. I need to link the figures to my text, therefore I need to use `\caption` and `\label` commands. It seems impossible to use floating figures inside blocks (maybe they are also floating objects?). It is possible to avoid this problem (still use the `caption` command, without using a floating figure)?

Thank you very much for any help.

PS: This is the code that reproduce my problem.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm,
     blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

 \title{Title}
 \author{Name}
 \institute{University}

\usetheme{Default} % Default, Basic, Rays, Simple, Envelope, Wave, Board, Autumn, Desert
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}
    \column{.5}
    \block[roundedcorners=40]{Fist block}{
    Some text: bla, bla, bla.
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{MyImage.pdf}
    \caption{}\label{}
    \end{figure}
    }

 \end{columns}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the `capt-of` or `caption` package, remove the `figure` environment (or replace it with e.g. `center`) and use `\captionof{figure}{<caption text>}`.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm,
     blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

 \title{Title}
 \author{Name}
 \institute{University}

\usetheme{Default} % Default, Basic, Rays, Simple, Envelope, Wave, Board, Autumn, Desert
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}
    \column{.5}
    \block[roundedcorners=40]{First block}{
    Some text: bla, bla, bla. See figure~\ref{fig:fog}.
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{Figure caption.}\label{fig:fog}
    \end{center}
    }

 \end{columns}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a built-in workaround, which is to use

```
\begin{tikzfigure}[Caption]%Figure environment does not work
 \label{test}
 \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{figure.pdf}
\end{tikzfigure}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think just embedding the label in the caption is sufficient:

```
\caption{ \label{figure} Caption ...}
```

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer (I know, that you can't comment other posts right now)

Comment: It would be better to expand your answer: for example you can check if the trick you were suggesting really works in a real document. If yes you can post the document in form of minimal working example.