# Trying to use sub-figures in a column on a tikzposter

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption, tikzposter, subfig

I'm trying to use sub-figures in a figure, within a block, that's in a column, on a tikzposter and instead of placing the figure and caption within the block they appear outside of it, in the middle of the poster (see picture)[image]. How do I get them to stay in the block?

```
\documentclass[24pt, a1paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\title{\textbf{title}}
\author{me}
\date{}
\institute{\small{institute}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
 \node[above right,opacity=0.65,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) 
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{backgroundsample}};

\block{\textbf{Text}}
{
Some Text  
}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{Also Text}
{
More Text Here

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.15\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{sample}
\caption{\textit{subcaption}}
\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.15\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.85\linewidth]{sample}
\caption{\textit{subcaption}}
\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{\textit{Some caption here}}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}



}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange - and thanks for posting a MWE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `float` environments
[do not work in tikzposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174856/floating-figures-and-tikzposter).

The general solution for defining figures and subfigures in tikzposter is:

```
% preamble
\usepackage{subcaption} -> \usepackage{subfigure}   % for subfigure captions
...
% body
\begin{figure} -> \begin{tikzfigure}                % figure environment
\begin{subcaption}{...} -> \begin{minipage}{...}    % subfigure environment
\caption{...} -> \captionof{figure}{...}            % figure captions
\caption{...} -> \captionof{subfigure}{...}         % subfigure captions
```

So, for your example (changes marked with `% <-`):

```
\documentclass[24pt, a1paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure} % <-


\title{\textbf{title}}
\author{me}
\date{}
\institute{\small{institute}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\node[above right,opacity=0.65,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {};
% {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{backgroundsample}}; % for now

\block{\textbf{Text}}
{
Some Text  
}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{Also Text}
{
More Text Here

\begin{tikzfigure} % <-
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.12\textwidth} % <-
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{sample}
\captionof{subfigure}{\textit{subcaption}} % <-
\label{fig:1a}
\end{minipage}% % <-
\begin{minipage}{0.12\textwidth} % <-
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.85\linewidth]{sample}
\captionof{subfigure}{\textit{subcaption}} % <-
\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage} % <-
\captionof{figure}{\textit{Some caption here}} % <-
\label{fig:1}
\end{tikzfigure} % <-


}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

which yields:

(I also: 1. commented out the background image, 2. adjusted the sizes of the subfigures to fit, 3. removed `[H]` as it is not necessary with `tikzfigure`)

[image: result]

Comment: UPDATE: the solution proposed by @John Kormylo is much better, as it allows you to make correct `\ref` calls. This solution will not give the right numberings -- e.g. try `\ref{fig:1a}`. Please accept the other answer and not mine.

Answer (score 1):

The tikzposter manual says "Due to implementation of the blocks, using the standard LaTeX figure environment is not possible."  It provides a tikzfigure environment, but tikzposter does not really support `\caption` or subfigures.

The remaining question is what to use for the width.  It appears that `\textwidth` and `\columnwidth` are too wide.  `\linewidth` works, but makes `0.15\textwidth` very small indeed.

```
\documentclass[24pt, a1paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}

%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myfigure}{\minipage{\linewidth}\def\@captype{figure}}{\endminipage}
\makeatother

\title{\textbf{title}}
\author{me}
\date{}
\institute{\small{institute}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
 \node[above right,opacity=0.65,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) 
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}};

\block{\textbf{Text}}
{
Some Text  
}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{Also Text}
{
More Text Here

\begin{myfigure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.15\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{\textit{subcaption}}
\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.15\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.85\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{\textit{subcaption}}
\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{\textit{Some caption here}}
\label{fig:1}
\end{myfigure}

}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```