# Add multiple arguments to figure

Tags: floats, optional-arguments, resize

I am placing a figure in my document using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{AlgorithmFlow.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:myLabel}
\end{figure}
```

I am using the `float` package to place the figure exactly in a specific part of the document. Nevertheless, it is also a pretty big figure so I want to resize it with the argument `width=x` but I am unable to place both arguments in the command. I am fairly new to LaTeX and I did not find out a way to do it and my searching did not yield any results (probably because I am unable to search for the specific terms).

Comment: What is wrong with `\includegraphics[width=x]{AlgorithmFlow.png}`?

Comment: I want to also use the `[H]` argument in addition to the width argument.

Comment: no the two things are separate, you want to scale the image with the options to `\includegraphics` and want to control the float position with `[H]` on `figure`

Comment: The `figure` environment resizes itself with the width of what it contains. Its options are only floating options, i.e. `H`, `h`, `t`, etc., `width` is not among them. However, `width` is an option of `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: If it is a large figure (anything more than half a page) `[H]` sounds rather unsuitable and the default float positioning likely to be better (or at least take far less manual adjustment to get a good page break)

Comment: Thank you so much! My problem was trying to place width in the wrong command like you pointed out. I might need to manually adjust the position since I am sending this to the other people I am doing this with.

Comment: You can always use a minipage and \captionof{figure}.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480945/trying-to-use-sub-figures-in-a-column-on-a-tikzposter/480951?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#480951