# Table with figures inside a table inside a tikzposter block

Tags: tables, includegraphics, tikzposter

I'm trying to put a table with figures inside a table in a "tikzposter" block environment. Whilst the method below works in `documentclass{article}` + `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`. It doesn't work in a `\documentclass[...]{tikzposter}` environment.

See code:

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{Simple}

\begin{document}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.5}
\block{block title}{
\begin{figure}[ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.32\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} XX @{}}
    \includegraphics{example-image}\hfill 
    \includegraphics{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics{example-image}
   \caption{Some text}
    &   \includegraphics{example-image}\hfill
        \includegraphics{example-image}\hfill
        \includegraphics{example-image} 
        \caption{Some text}
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
}

\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

For this I get an error message.

I also tried:

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.5}
\block{block title}{
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image} &  
                \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image} &
                \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image}
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Some text}
        \end{figure}
        &
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image} &  
                \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image} &
                \includegraphics[width=0.16\linewidth]{example-image}
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Some text}
        \end{figure}
    \end{tabular}
}

\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

For this I also get an error message.

Inside the block I'm trying to get the table to look like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174856/134144 seems to be related.

Comment: @leandriis there needs to be a `tabular` or something equivalent, that post doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The first example results in an error message since floating environments, such as `figure`, are not allowed inside of a `tikzposter`. The question, I linked to in my previous comment currently has three answers. The one to use for your case, is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174884/134144). As described there, take your first example code, remove the `figure` environment, add `\usepackage{capt-of}` to the preamble and replace all `\caption{...}` commands with `\captionof{figure}{...}`.

Comment: You mention "Table with figures inside a table"  as well as "there needs to be a tabular". Could you please explain this requirement. From the code you added I currently don't see the need for a second tabular environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Float environments had not to be inside box. Just remove `figure` environment and for caption use `\captionof{figure}{...}`:

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of} % <--- for captions outside floats

\usetheme{Simple}

\begin{document}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.5}
\block{block title}{
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.32\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X@{\qquad}X @{}} % <---
    \includegraphics{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics{example-image}\hfill
    \includegraphics{example-image}
   \captionof{figure}{Some text}
    &   \includegraphics{example-image}\hfill
        \includegraphics{example-image}\hfill
        \includegraphics{example-image}
        \captionof{figure}{Some text}
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!

Comment: @AlexLee, you are welcome :-)